# Rolling mean, standard deviation in dbplyr

Tags: r, mean, rolling-computation, dbplyr

I want to set a new variable with rolling function (rolling mean, stdev...etc.) in dbplyr

Here is a database

```
library(odbc)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver    = "SQL Server", 
                      Server    = "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
                      Database  = "stock",
                      UID       = "userid",
                      PWD       = "userpassword")

startday = 20150101
day = tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "LogDay"))
```

[image]

I'd like to calculate rolling mean over 5 days,
Here's my code, but it does not work

How can I solve this problem?

```
library(zoo)    
day %>% 
      mutate(ma5 = rollmean(priceClose, k = 5, fill = NA))

error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]키워드 'AS' 근처의 구문이  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]문을 준비할 수 
    <SQL> 'SELECT TOP 11 "logNo", "stockCode", "logDate", "priceOpen", "priceHigh", "priceLow", "priceClose", "adjRate", "volume", "amount", "numListed", "remark", "marketCap", "foreignRate", "personNetbuy", "foreignNetbuy", "instNetbuy", "financeNetbuy", "insuranceNetbuy", "toosinNetbuy", "bankNetbuy", "gitaFinanceNetbuy", "pensionNetbuy", "gitaInstNetbuy", "gitaForeignNetbuy", "samoNetbuy", "nationNetbuy", rollmean("priceClose", 5.0 AS "k", NULL AS "fill") AS "ma5"
    FROM "dbo"."LogDay"
    WHERE ("logDate" > 20150101.0)
    ORDER BY "stockCode"'
    Warning : 
    Named arguments ignored for SQL rollmean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occurring because `rollmean` does not have a dbplyr translation defined nor is it an SQL command that can be used without translation. This is unsurprising as `rollmean` is part of the data.table library and dbplyr focuses on translating dplyr and base R commands.

Part of what you are after is a window function. dplyr has a range of [window functions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/window-functions.html#types-of-window-functions-1), as does SQL, but translation between these is not always [straightforward](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/translation-function.html#window-functions-1). But there are ways to do this using commands that have translations defined.

Two possible approaches to consider:

**(1) combining lag and lead**

```r
df %>%
  mutate(prev2_price = lag(priceClose, 2, order_by = date),
         prev1_price = lag(priceClose, 1, order_by = date),
         next1_price = lead(priceClose, 1, order_by = date),
         next2_price = lead(priceClose, 2, order_by = date)) %>%
  mutate(ma5 = (prev2_price + prev1_price + priceClose + next1_price + next2_price) / 5)
```

This approach will not scale well, but it is straightforward and easy to reason about. If you want to work within groups (e.g. separate moving averages for each stock) apply a `group_by` before using `lag` and `lead`.

**(2) join and filter out records that are not wanted**

```r
df2 = df %>%
  select(stockCode, date, priceClose)

df %>%
  inner_join(df2, by = "stockCode", suffix = c("","_2") %>%
  filter(abs(date - date_2) <= 2) %>% # two records either side = window of width 5
  group_by(stockCode, date, priceClose) %>%
  summarise(ma5 = mean(priceClose_2)
```

This approach is much more general, but may be harder to reason about.

Comment: Thank you again, Simon. I appreciate your help.
As rolling function is not supported in dbplyr, I transformed table into data.table, applied rolling function and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
day = tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "LogDay")) %>% filter(logDate > startday) %>% lazy_dt()

dayt = day %>% 
   group_by(stockCode) %>% 
   arrange(logDate) %>% 
   mutate(rise = (priceClose/lag(priceClose,1)-1)*100,
          candle = ifelse(priceClose > priceOpen, 1, 0),
          middle = ifelse(priceClose > (priceHigh + priceLow)/2, 1, 0),
          ma5 = rollmean(priceClose, k = 5, fill = NA, align = 'right'), 
          ovnprofit = lead(priceOpen,1)/priceClose,
          disparity = priceClose/ma5*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

[mgirlich's comment](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/issues/604#issuecomment-1124563446) on this github issue (Request for time series function (lead, lag, rolling)) should be helpful here.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31758879)